# Manage the playhead using remote controls in background audio mode in iOS with AVPlayer

Tags: ios, audio, background, avplayer

I try to control that the user may advance seconds in song playback. I managed only for users can see the playhead but not interact with it.

I am using AVAudioSession in mode with AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback. AVPlayer and AVPlayerItem

```
_playerItem = [AVPlayerItem playerItemWithURL:url];
_player = [AVPlayer playerWithPlayerItem:self.playerItem];
```

[**EDIT**] This way, I control the remote events:

```
- (void)remoteControlReceivedWithEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    //if it is a remote control event handle it correctly
    if (event.type == UIEventTypeRemoteControl)
    {
        if (event.subtype == UIEventSubtypeRemoteControlPlay) {
            NSLog(@"Responds nice to the event UIEventSubtypeRemoteControlPlay");
        } else if (event.subtype == UIEventSubtypeRemoteControlPause) {
            NSLog(@"Responds nice to the event UIEventSubtypeRemoteControlPause");
        } else if (event.subtype == UIEventSubtypeRemoteControlTogglePlayPause) {
            NSLog(@"Responds nice to the event UIEventSubtypeRemoteControlTogglePlayPause");
        } else if (event.subtype == UIEventSubtypeRemoteControlBeginSeekingBackward) {
            NSLog(@"NEVER Responds!!!");
        } else if (event.subtype == UIEventSubtypeRemoteControlBeginSeekingForward) {
            NSLog(@"NEVER Responds!!!");
        } else if (event.subtype == UIEventSubtypeRemoteControlNextTrack){
            NSLog(@"Responds nice to the event UIEventSubtypeRemoteControlNextTrack");
        } else if (event.subtype == UIEventSubtypeRemoteControlPreviousTrack){
            NSLog(@"Responds nice to the event UIEventSubtypeRemoteControlPreviousTrack");
        } else if (event.subtype == UIEventSubtypeRemoteControlStop){
            NSLog(@"Responds nice to the event UIEventSubtypeRemoteControlStop");
        }
    }
}
```

How do I active the bar in remote controls (see screenshot) running in backgroud audio for doing it (iPhone blocked). Not even know if it is possible.

¿Is it possible to do it? In 'Music native App iOS' works fine!

[image: ScreemShot background audio player]

Answer (score 0):

The `AVPlayer` class has a `seekToTime:` method that will do what you want.

In your progress bar callback multiply the percentage represented by the progress bar position by the total media time and pass that value to `seekToTime:`.

Comment: I'm sorry. I am explaining wrong. I know how to forward seconds with AVPlayer (seekToTime:). But, How do I active the bar in remote controls (see screenshot) running in backgroud audio for doing it. Not even know if it is possible.